# Stoke's Theorem problem (direct calculation and using Stoke's Theorem)

Tags: cross-product, multiple-integral, stokes-theorem

Here are the question and my answer for the i) part. I have no idea how to do ii), but I know it has the same answer as the one in i)

> Let $\Gamma$ be the triangle consisting of the line segments $(3,0,0)$ to $(0,4,0)$, from $(0,4,0)$ to $(0,0,5)$ and from $(0,0,5)$ to $(3,0,0)$ Evaluate the line integral: $$\oint_\Gamma ydx+zdy+xdz$$ by (i) direct calculation, (ii) using Stokes' Theorem

(i) Directly: $$C_1=(3,0,0) \rightarrow (0,4,0)$$  $$C_2=(0,4,0) \rightarrow (0,0,5)$$ $$C_3=(0,0,5) \rightarrow (3,0,0)$$

Then,

$$\oint_\Gamma ydx+zdy+xdz = \oint_\Gamma (y,z,x)dr$$

\begin{align}C1: r(t)&=(3,0,0)+t((0,4,0)-(3,0,0)) =(3-3t,4t,0)\newline
r'(t)&=(-3,4,0)dt
\end{align}

$$\Rightarrow \int_{C1} (4t,0,3-3t)\cdot(-3,4,0)dt = -6$$

\begin{align}C2: r(t)&=(0,4,0)+t((0,0,5)-(0,4,0)) =(0,4-4t,5t)\newline
r'(t)&=(0,-4,5)dt
\end{align}

$$\Rightarrow \int_{C2} (4-4t,5t,0)\cdot(0,-4,5)dt = -10$$

\begin{align}C3: r(t)&=(0,0,5)+t((3,0,0)-(0,0,5)) =(3t,0,5-5t)\newline
r'(t)&=(3,0,-5)dt
\end{align}

$$\Rightarrow \int_{C3} (0,5-5t,3t)\cdot(3,0,5)dt = -\frac{15}{2}$$

$$\therefore \oint_\Gamma ydx+zdy+xdz=\int_{C_1}(y,z,x)dr+\int_{C_2}(y,z,x)dr+\int_{C_3}(y,z,x)dr=-23.5$$

Comment: I have edited the post to reflect your images, but please take the time to learn the MathJax markup language used on this website so people can be able to help you clearly =)

Comment: ok, I will. btw thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T$ be the triangle surface and ${\bf F}(x,y,z):=(y,z,x)$  the given vector field. Then Stokes' theorem says that
$$\int_{\partial T}{\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}=\int_T{\rm curl}({\bf F})\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby the orientations of $T$ and $\partial T$ are coupled in the usual way. In order to compute the flux integral on the right hand side of $(1)$ one usually has to provide a parametric representation $(u,v)\mapsto{\bf r}(u,v)$ of the surface in question. Then 
$$\int_T{\rm curl}({\bf F})\cdot{\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega=\int_{\hat T}{\rm curl}({\bf F})\bigl({\bf r}(u,v)\bigr)\cdot({\bf r}_u\times{\bf r}_v)\>{\rm d}(u,v)\ .  $$
But here is a simpler way since (i) ${\rm curl}({\bf F})=(-1,-1,-1)$ is constant and (ii) $T$ is a plane surface, namely half the parallelogram spanned by the vectors ${\bf a}=(-3,4,0)$ and ${\bf b}=(-3,0,5)$. The flux $\Phi$ in question then is just 
$$\Phi={1\over2}{\rm curl}({\bf F})\cdot({\bf a}\times{\bf b})={1\over2}(-1,-1,-1)\cdot(20,15,12)=-23.5\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer, but I can't add a comment.

Here's a page that explains the theorem and its use 
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/StokesTheorem.aspx